# variable outside of react component is rendered everytime component called?

Tags: reactjs, function, variables

```js
// something.jsx
let variable1;

const SOMETHING = () => {
return <div>..something</div>
}
```

if SOMETHING component rendered, variable1 is also rendered? (means declare every time the component rendered??)

PS. Im gonna use variable1 inside SOMETHING component!

Comment: What do you mean by "render" a variable?

Comment: which means declare every time the component rendered

Comment: No, the declaration (`let variable1;`) only happens *once*, when the module is imported.

Comment: thanks :)  I wanna make sure about that

Comment: what if it is imported several time ? the declaration happens several times?

Comment: What *problem* are you actually trying to solve here?

Comment: one of my colleague said that way causes change of variables so re-render happens. I wonder variables outside of component declared every time component is called.

Comment: I don't know what your colleague is suggesting, but updating the value of `variable1` *won't* cause the component to re-render if it's only referenced via the closure (as opposed to being passed as a prop, for example).